How to return both 400 or 422 depending on the model validation result?
I'm writing an API, which validates the payload sent by the user. Let's say the API receives a Zip code attribute "zipCode".
I want the model validator to return a 400 when the Zip Code is in invalid format, and return a 422 when the Zip Code is not in the range of valid zip codes.
From what I saw the validator returns 400 by default in case of any errors, and I can override this through apiBehaviorOptions to change it to 422. But I want it to return both depending on the error.
The payload is received through the body in the controller like:
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessRequest([FromBody] MyRequest request)
Is it possible?

Post the real code that does the actual validation and return the 400 result. Without it, it's impossible to know what's happening.

You could try following sample:
Zip.cs
    public class Zip
    {
        [MyValidation]
        public string zipCode { get; set; }
    }

MyValidation.cs
    public class MyValidation : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            int zipnumber;
            try
            {
                zipnumber = Int32.Parse(value.ToString());    //if cannot parse to int ,set to invalid format error
            }
            catch
            {
                return new ValidationResult("invalid format");
            }
               
            if (zipnumber < 400)  //Just assume the range is less than 400
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult("zipcode not in range");
            }
        }
    }

Program.cs   (check the errormessage to determine the errorcode)
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
{
    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actioncontext =>
    {
        var errorlist = actioncontext.ModelState["zipcode"].Errors;
        if (errorlist.Any(x=>x.ErrorMessage== "zipcode not in range"))
        {
            return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(actioncontext.ModelState); //422
        }
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(actioncontext.ModelState);   //400
    };
});

Test
post: {"zipcode":"abc"} and  {"zipcode":"532"}


